# File.Exists returned false for Url Type File Path

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have to deal with a file path like

```
file:///My%20HD/files/06.%20test%20Lastname%20-%20test.mp3
```

The file does exist and i have access to it.

But System.IO.File.Exist() returns false.

I guess the problem is the filepath format. How can i deal with it ?

Comment: Did you do Url decode?

Comment: That isn't a uri, `My%20HD` should be a drive letter.

Comment: Why do you expect `File.Exists` to work with URLs ? Shouldn't you be asking `How to convert a file URL to a file path`?

Comment: Not supported: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/path.cs#L646

Comment: I am so sorry. I forgot the "Mono" tag. this is a unix unc path. :(

Comment: Even so, `File.Exists` should work with a Unix path but not a URL

Comment: maybe i need libcurl for that.

Comment: Why don't you just use Uri.LocalPath? Why do you want to use a URL when a file path is expected?

Comment: I tried Uri.LocalPath and it looked good. But File.Exists is still false. I guess thats a Mono for Mac kind of thing.

Comment: What did `LocalPath` return? To put it another way, if Mono's `File.Exists` was broken, people would have noticed.

Comment: Does your process have the required rights to read the path to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Uri.LocalPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the file URL to an actual file path, eg:

```
Uri uriAddress2 =  new Uri(@"file:///h:/test.html");
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress2.LocalPath);
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(uriAddress2.LocalPath));
```

A file URL isn't a valid file path, local or UNC. `File.Exists` only checks if a file path actually corresponds to a real file.

In fact, as Caramiriel noted in a comment, Exists ends up calling [NormalizePath](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/path.cs#L646) which explicitly rejects URIs because many Win32 APIs can't handle them

The Mono version of File.Exits, just like .NET, [checks](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/MonoIO.cs#L237) the file attributes retrieved for a specific path. `GetFileAttributes` is an external call which probably ends up calling the equivalent Win32 API function, so file URLs won't work

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments. This is a strange issue. Here is the complete workflow. 1. I create a file in a 3rd party app on my mac which uses a file from my mac. 2. I save from the app. 3. I try to parse the file in my mono app. And now i get the UNC but cant File.Exists() it on the same machine?